# Is there any direct function to capture the required properties of Entity in List of Map from a list of Entity without looping?

Tags: java, list

```
public class EmployeeEntity{

  private int empId;

  private String name;

  private double salary;

  // Getter and Setters
}
```

**INPUT:** List of EmployeeEntity

**OUTPUT:** `List<Map<String,String>>` where the mapping is from propertyName to propertyValue. It should contain those properties I choose, not All properties in Entity.

Comment: How should the signature look like? `public List<Map<???, Object>> toMap(List<EmployeeEntity> entities)`? What's the domain of the mapping? Strings for the attribute names? java.lang.reflect.Field? How would you want to specify which attributes are required and which are not?

Comment: I Want Output As: List<Map<String,String>> where Map Key contains entity property and Map Value require propertyValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a direct function to solve your problems. But, with the use of `streams` & `reflection` you can achieve it.

```java
class EmployeeEntity {

    private int empId;

    private String name;

    // all arguments constructor

    // getters
}
```

```java
private Map<String, Object> toMap(final EmployeeEntity employeeEntity,
        final String... fieldNamesToExtract) {

    final Map<String, Object> employeeMap = new HashMap<>();

    final Class<? extends EmployeeEntity> employeeEntityClass = employeeEntity.getClass();

    for (final String fieldName : fieldNamesToExtract) {

        try {

            final Field declaredField = employeeEntityClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName);

            declaredField.setAccessible(true); // because the fields are private

            employeeMap.put(declaredField.getName(), declaredField.get(employeeEntity));
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {

            System.out.println("e = " + e);

            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    return employeeMap;
}
```

```java
final List<EmployeeEntity> employeeEntities = Arrays
            .asList(new EmployeeEntity(1, "A"), 
                    new EmployeeEntity(2, "B"), 
                    new EmployeeEntity(3, "C"));

final List<Map<String, Object>> listOfEmployeeEntityMap = employeeEntities.stream()
            .map(employeeEntity -> toMap(employeeEntity, "empId", "name"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write the reflection code for it though it's a way to implement it. But you can use Jackson API to convert the Java objects to Map or Properties with less line of code. Please check the below URL for the example code.
https://www.thetechnojournals.com/2019/10/how-to-convert-java-object-to-map-or.html